# Recommended way of creating test version of Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android

We have an Android app built with Mono for Android, and now we have desire to make a deployable test version for use in acceptance testing. It is important that the production version remains on the device and keeps working. What is the recommended way of creating a test build without causing interference like package name collisions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution applies to Mono for Android and allows you to change the package name of an application based on build configuration in Visual Studio:

1. Create a new *Build Configuration*, **Test**, for your solution.
2. Define a new *Conditional compilation symbol*, **TEST**, in your project.
3. Rename your existing `AndroidManifest.xml` to `AndroidManifest-Template.xml`
4. Create two .xslt files in the *Properties* folder:

   **manifest-transform.xslt**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output indent="yes" />
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="/manifest/@package">
       <xsl:attribute name="package">
         <xsl:value-of select="'<your.test.package.name.here>'" />
       </xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

   **manifest-copy.xslt**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output indent="yes" />
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
5. Add two `XslTransformation` tasks to the `BeforeBuild` target of your project file:

   ```
   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
     <XslTransformation 
       Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' != 'Test|AnyCPU'" 
       XslInputPath="Properties\manifest-copy.xslt" 
       XmlInputPaths="Properties\AndroidManifest-Template.xml" 
       OutputPaths="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
     <XslTransformation 
       Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU'" 
       XslInputPath="Properties\manifest-transform.xslt" 
       XmlInputPaths="Properties\AndroidManifest-Template.xml" 
       OutputPaths="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
   </Target>
   ```
6. Use the **TEST** symbol for conditional code:

   ```
   #if TEST
       [Application(
           Label = "App Test", 
           Theme = "@style/Theme.App.Test", 
           Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher_test")]
   #else
       [Application(
           Label = "App", 
           Theme = "@style/Theme.App", 
           Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher")]
   #endif
   ```

You can now switch between test and regular app by changing build config :)

Comment: Awesome! Seems to be just what I was looking for.

Comment: @khellang could you please help me out with this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270255/error-with-pre-build-event-to-change-package-name

Answer (score 0):

Changing the package name should probably be enough to keep things from conflicting, unless you are writing data to a hardcoded location, which would also need to be changed.

Comment: Changing the package name must be done in both manifest and all resource files, though. And this must be done back and forth every time we need a test build. Can this be automated based on e.g. a build configuration?

Comment: I was under the impression that when you changed the package name, you had to change the namespaces in your XML GUI files accordingly. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you use a custom view with custom attributes, you need to define a namespace to use them. Like: `<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.application">` and then use the app namespace: `<com.application.CustomView app:attribute="@string/AppName" />`.
This would be a problem when changing the package name of the application...